# Firefox cross structure with 3-D transform

Tags: html, css, transform, css-animations, pseudo-element

I have made a pen [By-pyramid structure](http://codepen.io/singhiskng/pen/dqiGj)
using pseudo elements.  [image: here is the image]

it working well in `chrome` but in `Firefox`
at both top and bottom, there is a `cross` like structure.
I don't know how to remove this.
can any one help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: I don't see the issue in Firefox 28, though it does not run near as smooth as in Chrome. Cool demo, btw.

Comment: thanks, may be its my Firefox 27.0.1 fault,but i want to know why cross is appearing.

Comment: @chris-hardie i updated my Firefox to Firefox 28 but still cross is appearing.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7, FWIW. Perhaps you should bring it up with Firefox directly?

Comment: I tried on other computers and it looks well. but on mine it's not.

Comment: Ping Firefox, provide a screenshot and a link to your fiddle along with your system specs. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, there might be an issue with the engine of the build you are using.

Comment: I have added a snapshot of my browser.

Comment: Works fine here. FF has more aliasing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that was a bug in my firefox.